# Есть ли функция а-ля unbind?

Tags: c++, linux

Есть ли возможность разбиндить порт? Или требуется закрывать сокет, создавать его и биндить заного?

Comment: разбиндить, или перебиндить:)? по логике русского языка, разбиндить - это просто закрыть сокет. а если после этого его снова открывать - то это уже перебиндить.

Answer (score 1):

Боюсь, что только "закрывать сокет, создавать его и биндить заного". Но это не проблема, если Вы сделаете свою ф-цию `unbind`, в которой всю эту логику и реализуете.

Comment: Спасибо. Было любопытно узнать :)